# How to customize the_archive_title()?

Tags: functions, child-theme

In my child theme's `archive.php`, I have the following code for displaying the title of my archive pages:

```
<?php
    the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
?>
```

But that displays my titles as "Category: *Category Title*" instead of simply the title without the prepended "Category: ".

My first instinct was to override `get_the_archive_title()` from `wp-includes/general-template`.  But from what I've read, apparently I'm not supposed to ever alter wordpress core stuff, even with overrides from a child theme.

So what is the best-practice way to control the output of `the_archive_title()`?

Comment: Post your solution as a separate answer. You can also unaccept mine and accept your own if you wish :-)

Comment: Oops, I thought I deleted this edit.  Your method ended up being better, so I meant to delete mine.  I'll do that now.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you look at [the source code of `get_the_archive_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_archive_title/), you will see that there is a filter supplied, called `get_the_archive_title`, through which you can filter the output from the function.

You can use the following to change the output on a category page

```
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', function ( $title ) {

    if( is_category() ) {

        $title = single_cat_title( '', false );

    }

    return $title;

});
```

Comment: This doesn't work on an archive page with a title of `Archive: Books` (where `Books` is a custom post type). The `single_cat_title()` function only returns a page title if the type is a *category* or *tag*. Can you amend your answer to include a solution that works with all content types?

Comment: @QuinnComendant Look at the source code, lines 1239 and 1240 :-). If you have an issue, simply ask a new question specific to your question

Comment: Right, one must return an alternate title for each taxonomy or post type they want different titles for. I've posted an answer that excludes prefixes from all types.

Answer (score 36):

The accepted answer works to remove the `Category:` prefix from category archive titles, but not other taxonomy or post types. To exclude other prefixes, there are two options:

1. Rebuild the title for all the variants used in the original `get_the_archive_title()` function:

   ```
   // Return an alternate title, without prefix, for every type used in the get_the_archive_title().
   add_filter('get_the_archive_title', function ($title) {
       if ( is_category() ) {
           $title = single_cat_title( '', false );
       } elseif ( is_tag() ) {
           $title = single_tag_title( '', false );
       } elseif ( is_author() ) {
           $title = '<span class="vcard">' . get_the_author() . '</span>';
       } elseif ( is_year() ) {
           $title = get_the_date( _x( 'Y', 'yearly archives date format' ) );
       } elseif ( is_month() ) {
           $title = get_the_date( _x( 'F Y', 'monthly archives date format' ) );
       } elseif ( is_day() ) {
           $title = get_the_date( _x( 'F j, Y', 'daily archives date format' ) );
       } elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format' ) ) {
           if ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-aside' ) ) {
               $title = _x( 'Asides', 'post format archive title' );
           } elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-gallery' ) ) {
               $title = _x( 'Galleries', 'post format archive title' );
           } elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-image' ) ) {
               $title = _x( 'Images', 'post format archive title' );
           } elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-video' ) ) {
               $title = _x( 'Videos', 'post format archive title' );
           } elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-quote' ) ) {
               $title = _x( 'Quotes', 'post format archive title' );
           } elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-link' ) ) {
               $title = _x( 'Links', 'post format archive title' );
           } elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-status' ) ) {
               $title = _x( 'Statuses', 'post format archive title' );
           } elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-audio' ) ) {
               $title = _x( 'Audio', 'post format archive title' );
           } elseif ( is_tax( 'post_format', 'post-format-chat' ) ) {
               $title = _x( 'Chats', 'post format archive title' );
           }
       } elseif ( is_post_type_archive() ) {
           $title = post_type_archive_title( '', false );
       } elseif ( is_tax() ) {
           $title = single_term_title( '', false );
       } else {
           $title = __( 'Archives' );
       }
       return $title;
   });
   ```
2. Or, simply strip anything that looks like a title prefix (which may alter actual titles which contain a word followed by the colon character):

   ```
   // Simply remove anything that looks like an archive title prefix ("Archive:", "Foo:", "Bar:").
   add_filter('get_the_archive_title', function ($title) {
       return preg_replace('/^\w+: /', '', $title);
   });
   ```

Comment: For titles containing spaces like `link type: tv` the regex must be `/^(\w|\s)+: /`

Answer (score 9):

Another option is:

```
<?php echo str_replace('Brand: ','',get_the_archive_title()); ?>
```

Replace Brand: with whatever text you are wanting to get rid of.

Its worth looking into the difference between get_the_archive_title() and the_archive_title()
the_archive_title() returns an array
get_the_archive_title() returns a string

Comment: the_archive_title() echoes the title and get_the_archive_title() does not, so they are basically the same. If you need to alter the content then you would use get.

Answer (score 6):

You could use

```
echo '<h1 class="page-title">' . single_cat_title( '', false ) . '</h1>';
```

Comment: This doesn't work on an archive page with a title of Archive: Books (where Books is a custom post type).

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy [`single_cat_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/single_cat_title/) uses `single_term_title` internally, which works on taxonomies as well. Make sure your theme doesn't have one of the following templates defined: `taxonomy-book.php` or `taxonomy.php`, because they have precendence over `archive.php`. Also, consider testing any of the methods in the other answers. This answer is quite old, it was working fine at the time I posted it, but I'm not developing for WordPress anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Ben Gillbanks [has a nice solution](https://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2017/02/hide-archive-title-prefix-wordpress/) that handles all post types and taxonomies:

```
function hap_hide_the_archive_title( $title ) {
// Skip if the site isn't LTR, this is visual, not functional.
// Should try to work out an elegant solution that works for both directions.
if ( is_rtl() ) {
    return $title;
}
// Split the title into parts so we can wrap them with spans.
$title_parts = explode( ': ', $title, 2 );
// Glue it back together again.
if ( ! empty( $title_parts[1] ) ) {
    $title = wp_kses(
        $title_parts[1],
        array(
            'span' => array(
                'class' => array(),
            ),
        )
    );
    $title = '<span class="screen-reader-text">' . esc_html( $title_parts[0] ) . ': </span>' . $title;
}
return $title;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', 'hap_hide_the_archive_title' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `post_type_archive_title()` to get the title of an archive without the "Archives:" text.

Comment: How do you display the post type archive title if 'get_post_type_archive_title()' doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead `the_archive_title()`. Works with CPTs and custom taxonomies.

```
<?php
$term = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$term_title = $term->label //works with CPTs (Books)
?? $term->name //works with custom taxonomy terms (gets Small in size/small)
?? "untitled";
?>
<h1><?php echo $term_title; ?></h1>
```