# Remove "Category:", "Tag:", "Author:" from the_archive_title

Tags: functions, archives

I have the following code in my theme's archive.php:

```
<?php the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>
```

This gives me titles like "Category: Russia", "Tag: America", "Author: John".

I would like to remove the "Category:", "Tag:" and "Author:" part and just display the category, tag and author names.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You can extend the [`get_the_archive_title` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_archive_title/) which I've mentioned in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/175903/31545)

```php
add_filter('get_the_archive_title', function ($title) {
    if (is_category()) {
        $title = single_cat_title('', false);
    } elseif (is_tag()) {
        $title = single_tag_title('', false);
    } elseif (is_author()) {
        $title = '<span class="vcard">' . get_the_author() . '</span>';
    } elseif (is_tax()) { //for custom post types
        $title = sprintf(__('%1$s'), single_term_title('', false));
    } elseif (is_post_type_archive()) {
        $title = post_type_archive_title('', false);
    }
    return $title;
});
```

Comment: That works! Thanks, Pieter! In case less tech-savy users are looking for the same solution: You add Pieter's code to your functions.php file and that's it!

Comment: Do this in a child theme so your changes won't get lost upon a theme update.

Comment: This works pretty well, but it's missing cases for archives and custom taxonomies.

Comment: See Ben Gillbanks' [solution](https://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2017/02/hide-archive-title-prefix-wordpress/) to all post type archives and taxonomies.

Comment: Just added support for CPT archives :)

Comment: doens't cover year

Comment: Old answer but still working. Thank you. Upvote from my side.

Answer (score 47):

Use function `single_term_title()`

Comment: You can do things many ways in WP, but I always opted for the simplest solutions. Thanks Timo.

Comment: Well that just doesn't work for all archives that aren't terms. So in my opinion not a very good solution.

Comment: @GDY could you tell, which non-terms should show in archives?

Comment: this returns 'null' to me, is there any setting that I should set?

Answer (score 22):

For CPT title Without word: ‘Archive’:

If you are building custom archive template for a CPT, and want to output just the title of the CPT with no extra word like “Archive” use following function instead:

```
post_type_archive_title();
```

From [developer.wordpress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_type_archive_title/)

Comment: Nice - this function is just what I needed. Note that the first parameter already defaults to and empty string and the second defaults to true which would echo out the result instead of returning it... so you could just use `post_type_archive_title()` to get the exact same result as `echo post_type_archive_title( '', false )`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 12):

as of Wordpress 5.5 you can remove the prefix with [this hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_the_archive_title_prefix/):

`add_filter('get_the_archive_title_prefix','__return_false');`

Comment: More context: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/408321/152624

Answer (score 11):

I feel like this is over simplifying things, but this is what I did...

```
<h1><?php echo str_replace("Archives: ", "", get_the_archive_title()); ?></h1>
```

Comment: this wouldn't work for an non-english website.

Answer (score 3):

`echo '<h1 class="page-title">' . single_cat_title( '', false ) . '</h1>';` 
in taxonomy-category.php outside public of theme.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a filter and put it in a file functions.php

```
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', 'replaceCategoryName'); 
   function replaceCategoryName ($title) {

   $title =  single_cat_title( '', false );
   return $title; 
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but really you should check is_category() before updating $title to single_cat_title, & if not is_category(), then just return the $title unchanged..

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to just have only the title without the prefix

```
single_cat_title();
```

Comment: While true, this has been suggested before in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the format is always: `Prefix: Archive Name`, we can just find the first colon followed by a space, and only show the content after this, using [get_the_archive_title()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_archive_title/) with PHP's [substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [strpos()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) functions.

```
<?php // Only show the portion of the string following the first ": "
  echo substr(get_the_archive_title(), strpos(get_the_archive_title(), ': ') + 2);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('post_type_archive_title', '__return_empty_string', 5);
```

Answer (score -6):

directory: `wp-includes`

file: `general-template.php`

find function: `get_the_archive_title()`
change:

```
if ( is_category() ) {
        $title = sprintf( __( 'Category: %s' ), single_cat_title( '', false ) );
    } elseif ( is_tag() ) {
        $title = sprintf( __( 'Tag: %s' ), single_tag_title( '', false ) );
    } elseif ( is_author() ) {
        $title = sprintf( __( 'Autor: %s' ), '<span class="vcard">' . get_the_author() . '</span>' );
    }
```

to:

```
if ( is_category() ) {
        $title = sprintf( __( '%s' ), single_cat_title( '', false ) );
    } elseif ( is_tag() ) {
        $title = sprintf( __( '%s' ), single_tag_title( '', false ) );
    } elseif ( is_author() ) {
        $title = sprintf( __( '%s' ), '<span class="vcard">' . get_the_author() . '</span>' );
    }//if you want to remove or just change text if you need to
```

Comment: Err, are you really suggesting hacking the core here?

Comment: This is a very, very bad idea. You cannot update now without creating a separate branch.

Comment: Sory if I break roles I give a word for that, but this is just another solution nothing malicious. So, you said that I hack my own site or I cant share code from core files?

Comment: Well, it's your website and you may edit whatever you want - even the core files. However, the web will break if you update your Wordpress...