# How to remove "Archive:" label from archive title

Tags: custom-post-types, archives

I need to remove "Archive:" label from the archive page title.
I tried this string without results:

```
<?php the_archive_title('<h2>','</h2>', false);?>
```

The title keeps displaying the "Archive:" label before the title.
How can I get rid of it?

This is the full code of my page:

```
<?php get_header('inner');?>

    <div class="row large-uncollapse">
        <div class="columns small-12 medium-12 large-12">
            <div class="breadcrumbs" typeof="BreadcrumbList" vocab="http://schema.org/">

              <?php if(function_exists('bcn_display'))
              {

                echo '<b>Sei in:</b>';
                bcn_display();
              }?>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row large-uncollapse">
        <div class="columns small-12 medium-12 large-12 large-centered text-center pad-vr-2">
          <?php echo get_the_archive_title();?>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php if(is_singular('rassegna-stampa')): ?>

    <div id="rassegna-stampa">
        <div class="row large-collapse">

          <?php
          if ( have_posts() ) :
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
              echo '<div class="columns small-12 medium-6 large-4 float-left" style="margin-bottom:10px;">';
              echo '<div class="columns small-3 medium-3 large-3">';
              if(has_post_thumbnail()){
                echo the_post_thumbnail();
              }
              if( get_field('file') ) {
                echo '<a href="';
                the_field('file');
                echo '" data-featherlight="iframe" target="_blank">';
                echo '<button>';
                echo '<img src="';
                echo get_site_url();
                echo '/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/pdf.png" width="20px">';
                echo '</button>';
                echo '</a>';
              }
              if( get_field('link') ) {
                echo '<a href="';
                echo the_field('link');
                echo '" data-featherlight="iframe">';
                echo '<button>';
                echo '<img src="';
                echo get_site_url();
                echo '/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/link.png" width="20px">';
                echo '</button>';
                echo '</a>';
              }
              echo '</div>';
              echo '<div class="columns small-9 medium-9 large-9">';
              echo '<h3 style="margin:0px;">';
              echo the_title();
              echo '</h3>';
              echo '<small>';
              echo '—';
              echo the_field('testata');
              echo '</small>';
              echo '<small>';
              echo the_field('data');
              echo '</small>';
              echo '<span style="font-size:12px;">';
              the_excerpt();
              echo '</span>';
              echo '</div>';
              echo '</div>';
            endwhile;
          else :
            echo wpautop( 'Sorry, no posts were found' );
          endif;
          ?>
        </div>
    </div>


<?php else :?>

    <div id="libri">
        <div class="row large-collapse">

          <?php
          if ( have_posts() ) :
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
              echo '<div class="columns small-12 medium-6 large-4 float-left" style="margin-bottom:10px;padding-bottom: 12px; height:220px;">';
              echo '<div class="columns small-3 medium-3 large-3">';
              if(has_post_thumbnail()){
                echo the_post_thumbnail();
              }
              echo '</div>';
              echo '<div class="columns small-9 medium-9 large-9">';
              echo '<h3 style="margin:0px;">';
              echo the_title();
              echo '</h3>';
              echo '<div style="float:left;width:100%;">';
              echo '<small style="float:left;width:auto;">';
              echo the_field('anno_pubblicazione');
              echo '</small>';
              echo '<div style="float:left; line-height:15px;">';
              echo '&nbsp;—&nbsp; ';
              echo '</div>';
              echo '<small style="float:left;width:auto;">';
              echo the_field('editore');
              echo '</small>';
              echo '</div>';
              echo '<span style="font-size:12px;">';
              the_excerpt();
              echo '</span>';
              echo '</div>';
              echo '<div class="columns small-12 medium-12 large-6">';
              echo '<a href="';
              the_permalink();
              echo '">';
              echo '<button style="width:auto; padding:0.4rem; float:left; border:1px #000 solid;">';
              echo 'Leggi tutto';
              echo '</button>';
              echo '</a>';
              echo '</div>';
              echo '<div class="columns small-12 medium-12 large-6">';
              if( get_field('link_acquisto') ):
                echo '<a href="';
                echo the_field('link_acquisto');
                echo '" style="color:#D34D3D;">';
                echo '<button style="width:auto; padding:0.4rem; float:left; border:1px #D34D3D solid;">';
                echo 'COMPRA';
                echo '</button>';
                echo '</a>';
              endif;
              echo '</div>';
              echo '</div>';
            endwhile;
          else :
            echo wpautop( 'Sorry, no posts were found' );
          endif;
          ?>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php endif ;?>

<?php get_footer();?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title not sure how that works with Archives.

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/179585/remove-category-tag-author-from-the-archive-title

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use the filter `get_the_archive_title`. It works like `the_title` filter.
More details about the function that embed the filter [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_archive_title/)

More in this question [remove category tag](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/179585/remove-category-tag-author-from-the-archive-title)

EDIT :

When it's a custom post type archive page, you might use another function to print the title : `post_type_archive_title()`
Then you'll be able to hook in the title with the filter `post_type_archive_title` , but there is no prefix for this function.

So in your template replace the call to `get_the_archive_title()` function with:

```
post_type_archive_title();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. 
It keeps diplaying "Archives:". I'm in the archive of a custom post type, can it helps?

Comment: Anyone can help in any way?

Comment: You need to look into your archive template. Update your question with its content. If you don't know which page is load, install query monitor plugin, it will provides all info.

Comment: Thank you, I've just edited the answer with the entire code.

Comment: I miss your first comment ! I edit my answer

Comment: Glad for you ! you can change some code with concenating the string like: echo '<img src="'. get_site_url() .'wp-content/uploads/2016/09/link.png" width="20px">';

Comment: Note that, if the post_type_archive_title filter does not appear to be getting rid of the Archive: prefix, it might be due to the theme or a plugin.  You should search your code and settings for any reference to this filter string.

Answer (score 7):

Also, you can remove unnecessary words from any standard title:

```
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', function ($title) {
  if ( is_category() ) {
    $title = single_cat_title( '', false );
  } elseif ( is_tag() ) {
    $title = single_tag_title( '', false );
  } elseif ( is_author() ) {
    $title = '<span class="vcard">' . get_the_author() . '</span>' ;
  } elseif ( is_tax() ) { //for custom post types
    $title = sprintf( __( '%1$s' ), single_term_title( '', false ) );
  } elseif (is_post_type_archive()) {
    $title = post_type_archive_title( '', false );
  }
  return $title;
});
```

Comment: Did you steal this from: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/179590/152624

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [get_the_archive_title()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_archive_title/) function, the prefix is now (since WP 5.5.0) wrapped in its own filter ([get_the_archive_title_prefix](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_the_archive_title_prefix/)):

```
$prefix = apply_filters( 'get_the_archive_title_prefix', $prefix );
if ( $prefix ) {
    $title = sprintf(
        /* translators: 1: Title prefix. 2: Title. */
        _x( '%1$s %2$s', 'archive title' ),
        $prefix,
        '<span>' . $title . '</span>'
    );
}
```

So you could use the filter to return an empty string (or anything you want) to overwrite the 'Archive:' text:

```
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title_prefix', '__return_empty_string');
```

or

```
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title_prefix', function($prefix) {
    /*$prefix is available for processing, too*/
    return __('your custom prefix: ', 'theme-text-domain');
});
```