# Remove "Category Archives: title" at the top of a category page

Tags: categories, pages, css, title, encoding

I created a category page that's linked to the main menu. It posts the categories fine, but it has the text "Category Archives:________" at the top of the page. Does anyone know to remove this. I'm using the twenty eleven theme.

Comment: See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/179585/remove-category-tag-author-from-the-archive-title

Comment: I think this question is different because I'm asking how to fix this issue within a specific theme: TwentyEleven.

Answer (score 2):

The text is coming from Twenty Eleven theme's `category.php` file.

There are two ways to remove it:

**A) Removing it using a Text/CODE Editor on the File System/FTP:**

> This is the recommended method

1. Go to `Your WordPress Installation Folder`.
2. Then `wp-content/themes/twentyeleven` folder.
3. Then open the `category.php` file in a Text or CODE Editor.
4. On line 20, you'll see this CODE:

   ```
   printf( __( 'Category Archives: %s', 'twentyeleven' ), '<span>' . single_cat_title( '', false ) . '</span>' );
   ```

   Comment out this line (better to comment out than delete, as you may need it in the future) with `//` in front of that line. So the line becomes like this:

   ```
   // printf( __( 'Category Archives: %s', 'twentyeleven' ), '<span>' . single_cat_title( '', false ) . '</span>' );
   ```
5. Save the file.

This basically makes the line inactive, so the title is not generated anymore.

**B) You can also edit from WordPress Admin Panel:**

> **Note #1:** This also works, but not recommended, as any error will lock you out of the Admin panel until you fix the error from the File System.
>
> **Note #2:** Your File System may or may not allow this. [Read More](https://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Editor_Screen).

1. Log in to WordPress Admin Panel.
2. Go to `Appearance` ➞ `Editor` from the left menu of the WordPress Admin Panel.
3. From the **Theme Files** list, Click **Category Template** (category.php)
4. Same as step (4) above.
5. Save the file by clicking the `Update File` button.