# How to remove "Category:" title prefix in Twenty Sixteen theme?

Tags: categories, title, theme-twenty-sixteen

I am using theme Twenty Sixteen. I created a menu using categories, and when I click on one and end up on a category page that has a "Category : ..." title. I would like to remove that title so that only posts are displayed.
I found this similar post : 
[Remove "Category Archives: title" at the top of a category page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/307727/remove-category-archives-title-at-the-top-of-a-category-page?noredirect=1&lq=1)
However, the theme files are not the same and I can't find a "category.php" file. Does anyone know where to find the line responsible for displaying that category title ?
I would greatly appreciate your help, thank you :)

Comment: Related: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/179585/remove-category-tag-author-from-the-archive-title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That title is coming from `archive.php` file of TwentySixteen theme.

You can find a `<header>` code section in that file.

What you can do, simply copy the `archive.php` file as `category.php`
and then remove the following code section from `category.php` file:

```
<header class="page-header">
    <?php
        the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
        the_archive_description( '<div class="taxonomy-description">', '</div>' );
    ?>
</header><!-- .page-header -->
```

In case you want to show only Category name as page title, then instead of removing the above code from `category.php` file, just replace the `the_archive_title` method with:

```
printf('<h1 class="page-title">%1$s</h1>', single_cat_title('', false));
```

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

To add to the previous answer, if you don't want to remove/add code to the PHP file, you can also add this via CSS to hide that section:

```
.category h1.page-title {
    display: none;
}
```

You can add this to style.css or go to Customize > Additional CSS

Comment: Thank you for that additional solution !

Comment: This did not work for me. Maybe it depends on the theme? I use traveler-blog-lite.

Answer (score 0):

To stop category title from displaying in the front end post. just follow below steps.
Add this line to additional CSS

`.cat-links { display: none; }`

Comment: Please try and include some sort of explanation when you post an answer.