# Set category page title in custom theme

Tags: categories, title

I'm new in wordpress. I am using one custom theme and install in wordpress.

I want to change category page title and remove "Category:" prefix from title. How can I manage it from admin ?

I don't know wordpress programming. So, I need to setup using admin panel.

Please guide me. Thanks !!

Page URL : http://localhost/tutorialsite/category/magento/magento-2/

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove "Category:", "Tag:", "Author:" from the\_archive\_title](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/179585/remove-category-tag-author-from-the-archive-title)

Comment: It's programmatically. I don't know programming of wordpress. I need to setup from admin.

Comment: @kero can you please help me how to solve it? I'm totally new in wordpress.

Comment: This is a programming community here (mostly). If you don't want to use custom code, I think [yoast plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) can do this for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `functions.php` of your theme file add the following code, taken from [Remove "Category:", "Tag:", "Author:" from the_archive_title](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/179585/remove-category-tag-author-from-the-archive-title).

```
add_filter( 'get_the_archive_title', function ($title) {

    if ( is_category() ) {

            //being a category your new title should go here
            $title = single_cat_title( '', false );

        } elseif ( is_tag() ) {

            $title = single_tag_title( '', false );

        } elseif ( is_author() ) {

            $title = '<span class="vcard">' . get_the_author() . '</span>' ;

        }

    return $title;

});
```

Of course you need to read about how the `functions.php` works. https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained

Comment: Can you please tell me how to check active theme folder ? I use this theme => https://wordpress.org/themes/blog-way/

Comment: There are four folders in my wp-content/themes folder. blog-way/twentyfifteen/twentyseventeen/twentysixteen

Comment: To see the active one you go to Appearance > Themes in your wp dashboard. Than you can go to Appearance > Editor and insert into the functions.php the code above. However, you should check the best practices to apply changes on your themes, before doing it.

Comment: The moment you update your theme this code will be gone. You should be using child themes for this or place the code inside a custom plugin

Comment: I completely agree with @kero.