# About title on a page

Tags: categories, archives, title

I would like to know how can I change the title of my page to be just "FinanzasYa" instead of "Category ArchiveFinanzasYa"

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I assume you want to change the archive for a category? I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for but I suggest you give just a few more details. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Comment: the solution depends on your theme; maybe start by looking into https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/179585/remove-category-tag-author-from-the-archive-title; and possibly contact your theme's developer for help.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to modify how a theme presents an archive is to create a [child theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=child%20theme) and then create a specific altered version of the page you want "fixed".

[Template files follow a hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) with the most specific file available used.

[image]

In your case, you could create a file called something like `category-finanzasya.php` (depending on the slug the category has - I've picked what it would probably default to). Copy the contents of category.php from your parent theme (that's the one you are making a child version of) and then edit it as much as you like.

For everything else, WordPress will use the original theme but, just for that one category archive, it will use your custom version.

Comment: Awesome Matthew, thanks for helping me out. I'm really a noob in wordpress so I would really appreciate if you could guide me on how to create that file and copying the contents from my parent theme to my child theme

Comment: I found that the best way to learn is by doing. Do a quick Google on "child themes" and you will find loads of step by step instructions far better than I could offer.