# Get current title of archive.php

Tags: archives, archive-template, wp-get-archives

I want to get current title at file `archive.php`

My code :

```
if ( is_category() ){ 
    echo "CATEGORY";
} else if( is_tag() ){ 
    echo "TAGS"; 
} else if( is_author() ){ 
    echo "AUTHOR"; 
} else if( is_tax() ){ 
    echo "TAXONOMY"; 
} else { 
    echo "ARCHIVE"; 
}
```

Is there a way to simplify this ?
I try this, but didn't work:

```
if ( is_post_type_archive() ) {
    post_type_archive_title(); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a new function introduced in Wordpress 4.1 called [`the_archive_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_archive_title/) which does just that. You can simply add `the_archive_title()` in your archive page.

If you need to filter the output, see my answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/175903/31545) on how to accomplish that