# How to display the_archive_title() and the_archive_description() - "weird" interaction

Tags: functions, filters, archives, custom-post-type-archives

I've got the following code in my "pagetitle" template partial:

```
<?php
the_archive_title( '<h1>', '</h1>' );
the_archive_description( '<span class="archive-description">', '</span>' );
?>
```

Now, what I expect to see in my page is this:

```
<h1>The Archive title</h1>
<span class="archive-description">The Archive description</span>
```

But instead I've got this:

```
<h1>Archive title <span class="archive-description">The Archive description</span></h1>
```

The description span enclosed inside the title h1. 
Why is that?

Note: I've previously removed the p tag from `the_archive_description()` using `remove_filter('term_description','wpautop');`

Answer (score 1):

I've solved using the solution posted by @Quinn Commendant in the following thread: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/203884/160016

In any case, the above behaviour is weird...